# Творительный или именительный падеж?

Tags: словообразование, падежи, окончания

Решил вынести в отдельный вопрос оставшиеся вопросы из предыдущего, поскольку там никто не отвечает.

1. Можно ли сказать: "Он был *хорош**ий** челов**ек***"? Если да, то равнозначно ли это фразе "Он был *хорош**им** человек**ом***"?
2. Можно ли сказать "Это стало не так очевидн**о**" (вместо "не таким очевидным") именно при наличии слова *"стало"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В позиции СИС именит. пад. часто конкурирует с творительным.
Ср.: ***В некоторых провинциальных уездах Казанской губернии (Мамадышский, Лаишевский, Тетюшский) каждый четвёртый присяжный заседатель был мусульманином < okмусульманин>, а в целом по этой губернии среди присяжных насчитывалось около 12 процентов татар. [«Отечественные записки» (2003)]***

Форма именительного падежа указывает на постоянный признак, творительный на временный. Так, в приведенном примере форма творительного падежа является двусмысленной: ее можно понять как постоянный признак, т.е. ***‘каждый четвертый присяжный заседатель являлся мусульманином в течение всей своей жизни’ или как признак временный ‘каждому присяжному заседателю довелось хотя бы какое-то время быть мусульманином’.*** *Хотя вторая трактовка маловероятна в силу внеязыковых причин, с грамматической точки зрения она вполне возможна. Употребление именительного падежа исключает эту двусмысленность.*

Обычно творительный падеж в этой позиции тем вероятнее, чем более знаменательной является связка: при связке быть творительный падеж употребляется редко, см. (21):

(21) Фред был хорошим инженером, но плохим менеджером. [«Computerworld» (2004)]

В настоящем времени творительный падеж в сходных контекстах встречается в виде исключения только в разговорной речи, ср. разговорный эллипсис в (22):

(22) ***Сын у нее в городе банщиком.***

Очевидно, что падеж в этом случае объясняется эллипсисом глагола семантической группы «работать», управляющего творительным падежом. Таким образом, здесь нет отношения конкуренции в одной и той же позиции. Случаи, подобные (22), стоят за гранью литературной нормы и ни разу не встретились в Основном подкорпусе. Данные Устного подкорпуса содержат единственный релевантный пример (23):

(23) Когда Грызлов выступил на съезде, отдельные лица поразились тому, что он говорил абсолютно общие слова, при этом ругал собственное правительство, в котором министром. [ «Эхо Москвы» (2003)]

Во всех случаях такого употребления наблюдается эллипсис знаменательного глагола, который косвенно подтверждается также и обязательностью обстоятельства места (в городе, в правительстве). В обычной же ситуации высказывания с пропущенной связкой допускают только именительный падеж, например, в (24):

(24) Отец, Александров Петр Дмитриевич, 1962 г. рождения, - старший научный сотрудник, зав. лабораторией НИИ г. Москвы. [Автобиография (2006)]

Как видно из сказанного, приведенный Вами первый пример абсолютно равнозначен в смысловом отношении.

Что касается второго примера, то скорее всего, и здесь можно говорить о равнозначности в силу внеязыковых причин. Хотя с формальной точки зрения, возможна двусмысленность.

***Русская корпусная грамматика.***

Comment: Забыл спросить, Серж, а что такое СИС?

Comment: СИС - это составное именное сказуемое.

Comment: А-а, понял, спасибо.

Comment: Простите, Серж. Не совсем согласна с данным утверждением "при связке быть творительный падеж употребляется редко". Мне кажется, что при употреблении в СИС глагола-связки "быть" именная часть чаще всего отвечает на вопросы КЕМ? ЧЕМ? КАКИМ? (именно в такой последовательности). А это всё творительный падеж. Намного реже именная часть выражается кратким прилагательным или кратким причастием.Проверено на практике.Примеров тому множество.

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли сказать: "Он был хороший человек"?

Можно. [См. примеры](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%CE%ED%20%E1%FB%EB%20%F5%EE%F0%EE%F8%E8%E9%20%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA%22):

*Нехлюдов почувствовал давно не испытанное им душевное состояние полного довольства собой, точно как будто он теперь только узнал, какой **он был хороший человек**.* [Л. Н. Толстой. Воскресение (1899)]

*Тем не менее **он был хороший человек** ― отзывчивый и справедливый, вечно за что-нибудь страдающий, полный беспокойства, тревоги и ожиданий.* [М. М. Зощенко. Возвращенная молодость (1933)]

> Если да, то равнозначно ли это фразе "Он был хорошим человеком"?

Равнозначно.

> Можно ли сказать "Это стало не так очевидно" именно при наличии слова
>   "стало"?

Конечно, можно. Раньше "это" было очевидным, но что-то произошло, и очевидность "этого" стала чуть меньше.