# Творительный и именительный падеж при именном сказуемом в прошлом и в будущем времени

Tags: грамматика

Иногда надо использовать творительный падеж в прошлом и в будущем времени.
Но я еще не понял когда надо его использовать.
Кто то может объяснить правило?

Comment: [Творительный именительного](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418847/%d0%a2%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6/418855#418855)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что Вас интересует. Если исходить только из вашего вопроса,то в русском языке нет правил, регулирующих употребления падежей в разных временах, иначе говоря, падеж от времени не меняется.

Ср.: Я пишу/писал/буду писать ***ручкой***. Время изменилось, падеж - нет.

Может, Вас интересует другой вопрос, тогда сформулируйте свой вопрос на конкретном примере.

Comment: Вы прав простите! Неправильно объяснил. Это правда что обычно существительные не меняют падеж но иногда и существительные и  прилагательные меняются падеж когда время меняет. На пример                

Она была хорошей подругой.

Почему тогда это правильно писать  "Я был занят"? Какая разница?

Comment: Я дал вам ссылку под вашем вопросом. Этот вопрос уже обсуждался.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!