# Окончание в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: окончания

Он был первЫМ человеком, кому удалось / Он был первЫМ человеком, кто смог //
Он был первЫЙ человек, кому удалось / Он был первЫЙ человек, кто смог

Как правильно?

Comment: А как думает lia Razbitnoi?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамматически все варианты возможны. Даже значительных стилистических различий не вижу. Более естественными выглядят два варианта с творительным падежом ("был первым").

Контекст дайте полностью, возможно тут какие-то смысловые заморочки.

> А в чем вообще вы видите семантическую разницу между творительным и именительным? Мне именительный тут кажется каким-то "неродным". – Morkovkin

Ну да, согласен. Неестественно тут именительный звучит. В этом и отличие. (Семантические - это уже ловля блох. Есть мнения на этот счет, но все разные.) Но тем не менее сейчас он становится довольно употребительным, правда обычно в более длинных фразах. –

В исторической характеристике - что он, типа, "архаичный"(?) - сильно сомневаюсь, он как раз становится популярным. Добро бы еще "архаический", но тоже, видимо, неверно. Обе формы весьма давние. А вообще упрощение падежной системы всегда признак новизны, а не "архаичности".

Про отличия именительного и творительного: [Творительный или именительный падеж?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418847)

Comment: А в чем вообще вы видите семантическую разницу между творительным и именительным? Мне именительный тут кажется каким-то "неродным".

Comment: *Онегин был, по мнению многих,... ученый малый, но педант.* И так далее, примеров просто навалом. Так что не "неродной", а просто слегка архаичный.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40046/discussion-between-behemothus-and-niemand).