# Какая или какой должна быть одежда?

Tags: падежи, окончания

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило согласования окончаний в данном случае.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Творительный или именительный падеж?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418847/%d0%a2%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6/418855#418855)

Comment: Верно ли я поняла, что употребимы оба варианта?

Comment: Юлия, см. мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Возможны оба варианта,** но в каждом случае надо выбрать один.

**1) Статистика:** Из Нацкорпуса: ***какой должна быть...*** ― 121 пример, ***какая должна быть...*** ― 54 примера.

**2) Правило**

[http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm#з_02](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm#%D0%B7_02)

1).    Обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж существительного указывает на у**стойчивый признак** предмета, на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – на **временный признак**.

5).    имя прилагательное в составном сказуемом независимо от типа связки (незнаменательные или знаменательные глаголы-связки) обладает **большей свободой в выборе формы творительного или именительного падежей. Но творительный падеж свойствен книжной речи, а именительный – разговорной.** Я бываю гадкая... (Л.Толстой). – Когда же я бываю любезным! (Тургенев). Мысль Викентия Алексеевича шла примерно теми же ходами, что и прохоровская, ассоциации были тождественными (В. Липатов). – Парень-то был ядреный, в плечах широкий (В. Белов).

**Остановимся на Т.п.**

Для современного языка Т.п. более характерен, стиль речи выбираем книжный,  временный признак можно связать с тем, что речь идет об идеале, к которому нужно стремиться.

Итак: **Какой должна быть одежда?** ― Одежда должна быть красивой, практичной, удобной.

Answer (score 1):

Теория говорит, что возможны оба варианта, при этом нужно учитывать смысловую и стилистическую разницу между ними (см., например, ответ Sharon). Но данное короткое вопросительное предложение имено в таком виде, как оно дано в вопросе, не употребляется с И. п., по-моему. Поэтому пишем: **Какой должна быть одежда?**

Comment: Вот предложение: Знают зрители, знают руководители кино ― все знают, какая должна быть картина. [Павел Сиркес. Труба исхода (1990-1999)] Можно переделать. Какая должна быть картина? Это знают все... Тут разница такая, наверное. Т.п. - это перечень необходимых качества. И.п. - это описание результата, представленный статичный образ. То есть выбор падежа может зависеть даже от контекста.