# В чем отличие между "проста и понятна" и "простой и понятной"?

Tags: синтаксис

1. Жизнь Ирины была простой и понятной.
2. Жизнь Ирины была проста и понятна.

Я правильно понимаю, что обе конструкции являются корректными?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именительный падеж указывает на постоянную характеристику (**Ирина была [всегда] проста и понятна**).
Творительный падеж указывает на временный признак (**Ирина была [в нашем диалоге] простой и понятной**).
Этот вопрос рассматривался на форуме неоднократно, подробнее см [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/447774/200790), [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/418855/200790).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.